# Last part of the string after the last delimiter - Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The spreadsheet I am working with has a lot of incorrect data, but for addresses, in most cases the postcode is at the end, but it is not always the case. Below is a sample of example records.

| address |
| --- |
| 11 Street; City; Area; AB1 2CD |
| 12 Avenue; AB2 3CD |
| AB3 4CD |
| SW3 |
| London AB3 2CD |
| Town |
| AB5 6CD; gb |
| n/a |

Desired result

| postcode |
| --- |
| AB1 2CD |
| AB2 3CD |
| AB3 4CD |
|  |
| AB3 2CD |
| AB5 6CD |

I am aware that there isn't a consistent way to retrieve everything, but it tends to be the last part of the string split by the last semicolon, so a helpful script would allow me to retrieve the last part of the string until the last semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

```
function strip() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1).getDisplayValues().flat();
  let vo = vs.map(s => [s.match(/\b[0-9A-Za-z/]+$/gi)[0]]);
  sh.getRange(2,2,vo.length,1).setValues(vo);
}
```

Output:

| address |  |
| --- | --- |
| 11 Street; City; Area; AB1 2CD | 2CD |
| 12 Avenue; AB2 3CD | 3CD |
| AB3 4CD | 4CD |
| SW3 | SW3 |
| London AB3 2CD | 2CD |
| Town | Town |
| AB5 6CD; gb | gb |
| n/a | n/a |

Comment: Thank you very much for the input. I am getting an error stating string is not defined when I click "Run". Can you instruct me on how to use the function? Also, from your table it seems to take just the last 3 characters of the postcode, I would like to get the whole string after the last semicolon (e.g. AB1 2CD)

Comment: The top line was not meant to be there.  It was something I put there before I had completed the answer.  Sorry.

Comment: If you like to work these kinds of problems out on your own then you might like to try regex101.com

Comment: Thanks for the update. Now it says cannot read property '0' of null. Also, I cannot tell what the code is doing and whether it is picking up the entire postcode string. Also, can you give a bit more details on how to learn to use regex101 and how to solve these problems myself please?

Comment: Please post the code exactly as you have it now.  I've tested the code and on the data that you have provided so I can't debug it in a vacuum I need to have a [mcve]

Comment: The code is copy pasted and for sh I put Sheet1 instead of Sheet0 because this is the sheet I have. Nothing else has been modified, I copy pasted and tried again a few times to make sure. The error states "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null Code.gs:5. I suppose it is the vo causing this because [0] is not clear to the system for some reason. As for the example, I have the list in the address column as the first column of Sheet1.

Comment: I made a change but I'm having no trouble on my side if it's the match then there must be something different in you data because it's not finding a match

Comment: Thank you for the update. Can you please provide more info on how to learn Google Apps script myself? Most resources out there show nothing about these functional problems, but just colouring or UI stuff. Should I be looking at functional JS or Data Structures? Do you have any suggestions for me?